# Saving data with Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor

How do I save data with Razor? If I create a form to gather customer details how do I then create a new customer like Customer c = new Customer(){name= nameTextBox.Name} if there are no server side controls? With Razor it seems easy to display data, but I just don't understand how we collect data like we do with Web Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller you get back the model in parameter:

```
public ActionResult Create(Customer model)
{
    SaveCustomer(model);

    return View();
}
```